# Two points random walk

Tags: random-walk

How can I build an algorithm which creates a random walk but subject to the constraint that I give the initial and final positions.

- How can I do it? Let's say I meet a drunk guy on the street. I know from where the guy came and also where we are.
- How would I create a possible random path in this setting? (let's simplify to $1$D problem).

Comment: Your algorithm should 1: set the start position at the required point 2: take a random step 3: check if we're at the end point. If not, return to point 2

Comment: @David Wow. That is not doable. With a walk of 100 steps, I have to get to initial position everytime (basically). And if I consider float numbers, it's not doable at all.

Comment: One possibility: precompute and tabulate many random walks. Then in real time choose one at random. (The statistics will probably not match those of a real random walk so constrained, but may be good enough for your application.)

Comment: If the length of the walk is given, instantiating a realization of the walk should be straightforward. Which distribution to draw the length from? Some googling yields [this](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pram/021/03/0187-0200). In the abstract they claim to calculate the exit time distribution

Comment: @Rodolfo That depends on the dimension you're making your walk and if you fix the number of steps. Please try defining your problem a bit more clearly

Comment: I can fix the numbers of steps, yes. But I wanted it to work with a normal distribution in terms of the variations. The best way I found so far was to initialize a flat array and then, pick an index and apply a random variation with center being the average value of the two adjacent elements, many times. But it takes to much time..